# Circular reference detected for service

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a simple class which looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Algorithm;

use App\Dao\MatchDao;
use App\Service\MatchService;

class Calculator {
    private $users;
    private $matchDao;

    function __construct(MatchService $matchService, MatchDao $matchDao) {
        $this->users = $matchService->users;
        $this->matchDao = $matchDao;
    }

    public function hourlyRate() {
        $query = $this->matchDao->getSingleColumn('Payment', 'hourly_rate', 32);
        var_dump($query);
    }
}
```

But I get the following error message:

> Circular reference detected for service "App\Algorithm\Calculator",
>   path: "App\Algorithm\Calculator -> App\Service\MatchService ->
>   App\Algorithm\Calculator".

**MatchService.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

use App\Algorithm\Calculator;
use App\Algorithm\Collection;

class MatchService {
    public $users;
    private $collection;
    private $calculator;

    function __construct(Collection $collection, Calculator $calculator) {
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->calculator = $calculator;
    }

    public function getMatch($data) {
        $this->users = $this->collection->getAllUsers($data);
        $this->calculator->hourlyRate();
        return 1;
    }

}
```

The problem would be `MatchService` but what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the definition for MatchService?

Comment: Something you are dependency injected in the constructor also dependency injects Calculator

Comment: @aynber sure, I have updated my question.

Comment: @MylesK that's true. So that means that dependency injection wouldn't work and I have to create a new instance?

Comment: `Calculator` requires `MatchService` and vice-versa

Comment: You have the Calculator in your MatchService constructor, and MatchService in your Calculator constructor. You'll have to adjust it so the constructors don't keep calling each other.

Comment: @aynber so how can I do this? I have tried it with `if (!isset($this->users)) { $this->users = $matchService->users; }` but I still get the same error.

Comment: From your posted Calculator code it looks like you are pulling users from your MatchService. Maybe inject Collection instead.  But from a higher level point of view,  your design does not look very robust.  MatchService::users is not set until MatchService::getMatch is called which means your Calculator constructor may not even have users available yet.  Take a step back and try to redesign your classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As several people have pointed out, the circular dependency comes from that fact that you are trying to inject the Calculator into MatchService and at the same time, injecting MatchService into the Calculator.  No way to create one before creating the other.

Looking a bit more deeply, it appears that Calculator is using the MatchService to get list of users.  As a second problem, Calculator is trying to get the users before MatchService has generated them.

Here is one possible refactoring:

```
class Calculator
{
    private $matchDao;

    public function __construct(MatchDao $matchDao)
    {
        $this->matchDao = $matchDao;
    }
    public function getHourlyRate($users) // Added argument
    {
        $query = $this->matchDao->getSingleColumn('Payment', 'hourly_rate', 32);
    }
}
class MatchService
{
    private $collection;
    private $calculator;

    public function __construct(Collection $collection, Calculator $calculator)
    {
        $this->calculator = $calculator;
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }
    public function getMatch($data)
    {
        $users = $this->collection->getAllUsers($data);
        $this->calculator->getHourlyRate($users);
    }
}
```

Removing MatchService from the Calculator's constructor solves the circular dependency problem.  Passing $users to getHourlyRate solves the problem of trying to get users before they are available.

This is course is just one possible solution.  It's not clear from your posted code if Calculator really needs $users or not.

Comment: Yes, Calculator really needs $users and not only for a single method but I have created a main method in Calculator, which needs a parameter (just like your code) and that main method will just create a property with `$this->users = $users`, so that it will be useful for all the other methods inside the Calculator class. But thanks for your answer. That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This usually occurs when classes are dependency injecting each other, hence the circular reference.

Given you above example, your class `MatchService` injects `Collection` and `Calculator`. One of these (would assume calculator as collection is probably a doctrine class) dependency injects your `MatchService`.

Here is how I imagine your classes are supt:

```php
class MatchService 
{
    public $users;
    private $collection;
    private $calculator;

    public function __construct(Collection $collection, Calculator $calculator) {
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->calculator = $calculator;
    }
}

class Calculator
{
    private $matchService;

    public function __construct(MatchService $matchService)
    {
        $this->matchService = $matchService;
    }
}
```

You have a couple of options:

- More services with fewer dependencies
- Using statics

It's hard for us to solve for you as it's dependent on how you architect your application.

Comment: The posted code actually shows the circular dependency quite clearly.  Not sure how useful generic foo bar answers are in this case.

Comment: My code example is supposed to show circular reference

Comment: Sure but instead of foo and bar (or even apples and oranges) why not show the actual circular reference?  And suggesting statics as a possible solution?  Hmmm.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect his code, thanks for the suggestion. Statics can solve the problem but really its how he has designed his application, so you don't have many ways to fix it.

Comment: I don't really mean to be harassing you and I know we are supposed to be kind but I really have no idea what you trying to accomplish with this answer.  It's certainly not a suggested fix.  In any event, have a useful day.

Answer (score 3):

It is kind of obvious that you are injecting service A into Service B, and, also, Service B into Service A .
Seems kind of not logical to do so, but sometimes is needed. 
In my case, I have two services :

_MySesion -> Which prototypes Symfony Session

_MyClient -> Responsible for identify the client and get its DB Credentials

I use the MySession to store those credentials, as so, it will be available to the whole system, but, to get those credentials using MyClient, I need some info stored into MySession .... See, two services that need each other to work ...

I start to see this same

> Circular reference detected for service

just after upgrade to Symfony 5. And, sfy5  itself suggested the solution :

```
composer require symfony/proxy-manager-bridge
```

Remember that the services may be set with

```
lazy : true
```

More info on [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html)